# Git pull fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed even though repo less than 10 kb

Tags: git

I've seen there are a lot of similar questions, however, my folder is very small... less than 2 mb. With the .gitignore, it's 5 files and maybe about 10 kb of stuff. The remote repo is empty save for a readme. When I try to pull it, I get the error

fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1874919423 bytes).

Comment: If you've seen lots of similar questions, did you check them all to see if their solutions fixed it for you?

Comment: Most of them yes. They're either about very large repos or self-hosted repos. My repo is hosted on GitLab cloud.

Comment: Strange thing is that GitHub desktop IF I create the repo on GitHub.com and clone it to my local machine. Any other way gives me the error above.

Comment: Which git version are you using?

Comment: @Lasse 2.21.0.windows.1

Comment: I don't know anything about this problem, so right now I'm only throwing out things off the top of my head. Do you have a proxy setup? Could it be that the proxy is returning non-git-protocol data?

Comment: Your folder is small, less than 2MiB, has it ever been bigger? For instance, at some point, did you commit a 1GiB file, but then in a later commit deleted it? Is your .git folder less than 2MiB, or your working folder?

Comment: No proxy. I'm at home trying to push to GitLab.
No, never. It's a tiny project I just started. The .git folder is currently 60kb on disk. The total size of the working folder with the git folder is ~1.6mb.